# Unwanted http re direction to https iis 7

Tags: ssl, iis

I don't know what happened but I think my IIS is broken.

When I was setting up my website to use the https 443, I created a binding and a self-signed certificate. It's working fine but after I revert back all the changes I did and removed the bindings my site always redirects to https even though the https bindings is disabled. How can I revert it back to its original state where it's working on an http binding only.

I already tried re-installing my IIS and all its features but nothing happens, it still routes to https:\localhost.

Comment: IIS does work weird sometimes. What happens when you manually enter _http://_ with localhost? I believe it would work! In addition to this, can you confirm what URL you have setup in web project properties for LocalIIS or IIS Express?

Comment: Check your web browser please. Certain browsers would be "smart" enough to switch to https while you don't really like that.

Comment: Rohit416 Yes, I will work if i manually type the link but if it's coming from IIS and clicked the browse it will automatically route to https://localhost.

Comment: Lex Li i already did, in fact i already cleared the ssl cache, browser cache and still doesn't work.